# Win-Lose Model appropriate if primarily only one outcome

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit, elections

Question: Is it appropriate to use a multinomial logit if there is only a single outcome for all but one of the three possible outcomes? How could I reframe to incorporate the possible outcomes.

Background:
I am modeling a three-horse (or elephant) race (Trump, Kasich, Cruz) for the state of New York (The Republican Party Primary), and I have a dataset with 62 records that looks like this:

```
County      |Winner |Trump Votes|Cruz Votes | Kasich Votes | Demographic Variables...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cattaraugus |1      |1000       |       500 | 700          | .57
Erie        |1      |39589      |      7964 | 13136        | .38
```

I was planning on using a multinomial logit (multinomial logistic regression) to determine significant independent variables, however ...

it just so happens that one horse / elephant (Trump) wins all but one of the data points (counties) in my dependent variable (Candidate). One of the three candidates does not show up in my dependent variable as a victor of any county, while the third wins only one county.

**Would this be a poor sample/dataset to use a multinomial logit on?**

If so ...  I also have individual votes for each candidate so that they could be ranked as 1st, 2nd, 3rd or by some percentage margin etc.  Is there be a better way to code these in this instance?

Note: [Here is a little more background on my analysis via a question asked earlier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261245/is-a-win-lose-model-for-three-presidential-primary-candidates-appropriate-multi)